# How to get array values as string?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this array

```
Array ( [0] => User Object ( [id] => [username] => [password] => $2y$10$JJkkoa89X0gNmaEtzeLsI.GkKXqWx8R18MoHwglZkXkDPo5PdlnZe [first_name] => [last_name] => ) ) 1
```

can i get password as string ?

Comment: `$arr[0]['password']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password is hashed, i.e., some algorithm has been used to encrypt the original string. There are two ways

- Either you find the appropriate algo and decrypt it
- Just comparisons are possible. The comparison of actual password string with this hashed value will return true, so no need to get the original password string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the casting operators

```
 $password = (string) $arr[0]['password'];
```